# Accumulator/Online percentile calculation (e.g., with boost accumulator library)

Tags: c++, boost

I saw that boost offers a lot of convenient methods in the accumulator library to get e.g. a value (let's say 1234) corresponding to a certain quantile (let's say 0.995). What I would need is the opposite (input=1234, output=0.995).
Is there an elegant way to calculate/estimate the percentile of value in an online fashion (=while accumulating) and without storing all values?

One thing I came up with is using extended_p_square_quantile with many probabilities and then do a binary search over the values output by the quantile function.

Do I miss something from the documentation and is there an easier way to directly get the percentile from the value?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.weighted_p_square_quantile

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how the weighted version would help for my problem. This version takes the quantile_probability as parameter and outputs a value that corresponds to it. I, in contrast, want to input a value and get back the (estimated/interpolated) quantile_probability.